# Correct schema design for InfluxDB for use with Grafana?

Tags: python, grafana, influxdb

I have various security cameras set to trigger when motion is detected. A program then grabs a still image from the camera, runs it through some deep learning stuff, and attempts to classify various objects in the image. I then log the results of the object classification into InfluxDB so I can use Grafana to browse how frequently various objects are detected, the classification confidence of the different objects, etc. The cameras process and classify a couple thousand motion events per day.

Here is a snippet of Python code that demonstrates my schema:

```
event_name = "object_detection"
camera_name = "front"
label = "person"

json_body = [{
'measurement': event_name,
'tags': {
    'camera': camera_name,
    'label': label,
},
'time': data['timestamp'],
'fields': {
    'confidence': prediction['confidence'],
    'min_confidence': prediction['min_confidence'],
    'alert': prediction['alert'],
    'y_min': prediction['y_min'],
    'x_min': prediction['x_min'],
    'y_max': prediction['y_max'],
    'x_max': prediction['x_max'],                
}
}]
```

The problem I'm having is that I can't (easily) query this data in Grafana--I just get an empty dataset. But if I drilldown in the query inspector, I do see the data. It's just heavily nested.

[image: Grafana screenshot]

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong in InfluxDB or in Grafana? Interestingly, the InfluxDB Python library uses this [example schema in the docs](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-python):

```
>>> json_body = [
    {
        "measurement": "cpu_load_short",
        "tags": {
            "host": "server01",
            "region": "us-west"
        },
        "time": "2009-11-10T23:00:00Z",
        "fields": {
            "value": 0.64
        }
    }
]
```

So now I'm confused? Should I breakout each of my field values into it's own datapoint? It would make querying in Grafana easier, but seems like an inefficient solution. What's the best option?

Answer (score 0):

Data schema looks perfect. Only Grafana query can be a problem. But I'm not sure what are you trying to query. It looks like you are trying to find hourly confidence maximum. So it is normal, that InfluxDB return `null` for hour where you don't have any matched records. Use fill if you want to customize that behavior. Doc: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/query_language/explore-data/#group-by-time-intervals-and-fill